# Issue displaying img in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, trouble-tickets

I noticed a weird problem with a site. When I view [site](http://son.sites.unc.edu/) in chrome or safari I can see an image at the very top of the page, however, when I view the same site in firefox the image does not display. Yet, when I look at the source code I find that the image is still in fact written in there, even though it does not display on the page. I was wondering if anyone had an idea what is going on? I've tried reseting firefox, clearing caches and cookies, and even switching the default security behavior of firefox with no results.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the following selector you have z-index value of -1 and this make the image behind the content so you can't see it on firefox it didn't affected on chrome or safari but affected firefox so you need to change in the selector the value of z-index to be 0 or higher than 0 anyway

```
.header-logo, .brand-logo {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

try to inspect you will see what I talked about in the inspector and by the way these css codes in your html file internal not in your css file so that I think you can't find the reason for whay the image is not displayed